# How to make Emacs recognize sentences after a set of parentheses/brackets?

Tags: emacs, navigation, whitespace, sentence

I am trying to use Emacs's `sentence-end` functionality to navigate around a file with citations (and double-spaces between sentences), and I'm having some trouble trying to get Emacs to recognize sentences with brackets/parentheses after a period.  For example:

```
Some text.  "Some quote."  (Something in parentheses.)  Something with a citation.[cite]  Some more text.
```

Using Emacs's built-in `forward-sentence` and `backward-sentence` works fine with the first, second, and third double-space sentence breaks in the example above, but the fourth sentence break is not recognized.

Interestingly, enforcing `(setq sentence-end-without-period t)` seems to also ignore double spaces when a set of brackets are in place.  In the example below, Emacs can delineate between sentences one, two, and three—but it will combine sentences four and five:

```
Sentence one  Sentence two.  Sentence three  Sentence four.[cite]  Sentence five.
```

Is there a way to make Emacs demarcate sentences by ALL instances of double-spacing, at least after parentheses/brackets?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The docstring of a user option `sentence-end-base` says, that it is a variable set to a

> Regexp matching the basic end of a sentence, not including following space.

The default regexp is `[.?!…‽][]\"'”’)}»›]*` currently. It [translates into](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/eintr/sentence_002dend.html) matching one of `.?!…‽`, including followed by any number of `]\"')}`.

Hence, it should identify the sentences in the test snippets you have provided with a condition there's a period right before a closing paren/bracket.

[image: Without dot ending a cite]

[image: With dot ending a cite]

[I agree we may expect sentences without a period to be identified having `sentence-end-without-period` disabled; this requires more look into how exactly the function `sentence-end` utilizes these two variables. Looks like it works only for the cases without paren/bracket involved. This might be a bug in Emacs behavior or --more probably-- documentation not explaining it well enough, so `M-x report-emacs-bug` perhaps.]

If the default behavior doesn't suit your needs, adjusting the value of `sentence-end-base` could be a solution. For example, consider any closing bracket (before spaces) to be a mark of an ending sentence with

```el
(setq sentence-end-base "[.?!…‽][]\"'”’)}»›]*\\|]")
```

[Illustration below uses a bit different regexp syntax. All the illustrations match the behavior I have in Emacs.]

[image: Bracket ends sentence]

Comment: Thank you—this is great!  One small point is that your suggested regex ends up including all periods (including mid-sentence periods, such as in decimal places like "0.00").  However, I was able to achieve the desired effect by slightly modifying your regex to the following: `(setq sentence-end-base "[]\"'”’)}»›]  \\|[.?!…‽][]\"'”’)}»›]*")`.